# Xcode - How to attach a tab bar to a view without adding a tab for the new view

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, tabbar

I have an application which has 5 tabs. I also have another view which you can access from tab3 via a selection of buttons. I will call it view 3b. View 3b populates with information based on which button the user selected in view 3. After the user puts in all the information required the app automatically takes them back to view 3. I want to add the tab bar to this view(3b) but I do not want it to have its own tab. I just want to use it so the user can navigate out of this view back to the rest of the app if they want to exit the screen early. Does anyone know how I can attach the tab bar to this screen without having a tab added for this screen. I am using Xcode 4.6.2 and am using storyboards to set up my app. 
Any help would be appreciated. I've done a bit of searching but everything I find just explains how to use tabs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By `view` you want to say UIViewController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a UINavigationController.

When you set up your UITabBarController, instead of linking the third tab directly to your 3rd view controller, connect it to a UINavigationController, and then set the root view of that UINavigationController as the UIViewController you want as your third tab.

From there, you can set up your buttons to perform a push segue to your second view controller (view 3b from your question).  If you do this, not only will you keep the tab bar on view 3b, but a back button will automatically be placed in the top left of the page so the user can simply go back to view 3.  If you don't want the navigation bar that appears to be there, you can instead uncheck the "shows navigation bar" checkbox in the UINavigationController's attributes inspector.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou so much. That worked exactly as you said. You are awesome and just solved much aggravation. This is my first time using xcode to actually make anything and when I took it in school it was before storyboards started being used.